# Run ./configure script as user under Alpine Linux

Tags: compiling, error-handling, alpine-linux

I’m trying to compile a program from source under Alpine Linux. When I run `./configure` under root everything goes well, but when I do the same as a normal user I get:

```
./configure: This script requires a shell more modern than all
./configure: the shells that I found on your system.
./configure: Please tell bug-autoconf@gnu.org about your system,
./configure: including any error possibly output before this
./configure: message. Then install a modern shell, or manually run
./configure: the script under such a shell if you do have one.
```

I tried `bash`, `ash` and `sh`, same message every time. Searched the web and this website for a solution, but can’t find it.
Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: What program is that? If it's open source can you post a link to it?

Comment: [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

Comment: You would probably need to dig into the `config.log` file for clues as to why this is happening

Comment: I ran Alpine using official Docker container, ran `apk add build-base` to install gcc and stuff and was able to run `./configure` w/o errors. There must a problem with your installation. How did you install Alpine?

Comment: I'm using an x86 emulator on my iPad called [iSH](https://ish.app/), so I didn't install it myself. There is no `config.log`. It looks indeed like a local problem. I'll take it up with them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe root has permission to execute a shell that the user does not have permissions to. Or it could just be poor error handling in the app and it's just a permissions issue.